# Авторизация на gosuslugi

Tags: python, selenium, requests

Раньше для авторизации с помощью Python на госуслугах использовал selenium для выполнения автоматизированного заполнения и отправки формы авторизации, после этого отправлял запросы с помощью request. На данный момент после заполнения логина и пароля нужно ввести капчу. Не могу придумать способ для обхода ввода капчи.

Comment: Капчу не нужно обходить, её нужно вводить

Comment: Можете попробовать распознавать символы на ней, но мне кажется, что на Госуслугах капча неплохая, и такой подход не сработает. В качестве альтернативы можно использовать сервисы по распознаванию капчи, ну или самому вводить...